# Electrical network of current sources - What happens if one source is defect?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, voltage

Suppose you have connected in a parallel circuit a pair of, say for the sake of concretness 5 sources of 300 mA and 0,5 V each, which are themselves connected together in series. Hence, in total one has 10 sources.

I am wondering what happens if one of these sources is defect, i.e. is formally replaced by a infinitely high resistor? More concretely, I'm interested in the change of the    open-circuit voltage.

After some thoughts about this problem I came to the conclusion that the voltage should decrease compared to a series of 5 sources, although more sources are involved. I expect that at each end of the parallel circuit one obtains the average of both potential values, where on the defect side only the sources right respectively left to the defect source are counted.

In particular, the open-circuit voltage should depend on the position of the defect source in the circuit.

Could you check my thoughts and give me a clear explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question, you have a set of 5 'good' sources in series.  You also have 4 'good' sources and 1 source that starts out 'good' but turns into an infinite resistor, which are in series.  You connect the two sets in parallel, and then measure the open-circuit voltage between the two ends.

The short answer is that nothing would happen to the voltage, though if you attached a load the current would change.

Potential difference is path-independent, so consider going from one end of the 'good' branch to the other end, through 5 sources.  Before and after the 'bad' branch was changed, the voltage through the 'good' branch is still due to the 5 sources, with 2.5 V total.

However, suppose we have these sources connected to a 5 Ohm resistor.  In your initial setup (all 10 sources are 'good'), the voltage across the resistor is 2.5 V, so the current through the resistor is 0.5 A.  The two branches of sources are identical, so 0.25 A flows through each side.

Now break one of the sources so it become an open circuit with infinite resistance.  The voltage across the network of sources is the same, so the voltage across the resistor is the same.  The current through the resistor is also the same, but now it's all coming from the 'good' branch, so the current through the 'good' branch has doubled to 0.5 A.